# SQLAlchemy: select nested columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, foreign-keys

I have following models and associations. AA can have multiple BB i.e AA.bbs is a list of BB. I want to select only few columns from AA and BB i.e name of AA and name, username from BB.

```
aa2cc_association = Table(
        'aa2bbassociation',
        Base.metadata,
        Column('aa_id', Integer, ForeignKey(get_full_table_name(TABLE_FOLDER_NAME) + '.id'), primary_key=True),
        Column('username', Unicode(512), ForeignKey(get_full_table_name(TABLE_FOLDER_TEST_NAME) + '.username'), primary_key=True),
        **_tablekwargs)


class BB(Base):
    id = Column("id")
    name = Column("name")
    username = Column("username")


class AA(Base):
    id = Column("id")
    name = Column("name")
    bbs = relationship(BB, secondary=aa2cc_association, backref='folders', lazy="joined")
```

Table AA

```
id    name 
1     aa1
2     aa2
```

Table BB

```
id    name  username 
1     bb1    u1
2     bb2    u2
```

Table aa2bbassociation

```
aa_id username
1     u1    
1     u2
```

I perform this query

```
results = session.query(AA.id, AA.name, BB.name, BB.username).group_by(AA.name)
```

But it returns only one row.

Returned result table

```
AA.name  BB.name  BB.username
  aa1      bb1       u1
```

I am expecting something like this. How can I get this?

```
   AA.id    AA.name  BB.name  BB.username
      1      aa1      bb1       [u1, u2]
```

Comment: Don't use `group_by(AA.name)`. That makes one row per name.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a join instead:

```py
results = session.query(AA.id, AA.name, BB.name, BB.username).join(AA.bbs)
```

[simple-relationship-joins](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/select.html#simple-relationship-joins)